# Collatz Conjecture in Python

Tags: python, math, collatz

I'm relatively new to Python and I decided to try and code a relatively simple collatz conjecture where the user enters a number (integer). The code is just a simple function that calls itself. i is a list that should have every number that the function calculates appended to it. I'm new to executing Python scripts and I have tried using the IDLE shell to run the code. It asks me what number I want but when I enter a number nothing is printed? I'm sure I just need to edit a small bit of this code (or maybe it's all wrong yikes) but does anybody have any idea why my script returns nothing? Sorry about this and thanks.
Here's the code:

```
l = input("Enter a number: ")
l = int(l)
i = []
def collatz(n):
    if n==1:
        return i
    if n%2 == 0:
        n = n/2
        i.append(n)
        return collatz(n)
    else:
        n = ((n*3) + 1) / 2
        i.append(n)
        return collatz(n)
    print(i)
collatz(l)
```

Comment: The `print` statement is unreachable - when do you anticipate your program reaching it?

Comment: BTW, since you are dealing with integers you should be using the `//` floor division operator instead of `/`, which always returns a float in Python 3.

Comment: Unless you are doing this as an exercise in recursion, a recursive Collatz is probably a bad idea. You will blow the stack with (some) larger numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three `return`s before your `print` and one of them is inside an `else` statement, which means that at least one of them will be executed, so your `print` won't even be reached to be executed, you should move it right after the function definition to see something:

```
def collatz(n):
    print(i) # <= print here
    if n==1:
        ....
```

See more about the [`return statement`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#return). A snippet:

> [`return`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#return) leaves the current function call with the expression list (or `None`) as return value.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, all of the execution paths in your function end in a `return` statement, so that `print` call is unreachable. So if you want each value of `n` or `i` to be printed you need to move the call to somewhere that it *will* be reachable. ;)

Also, there's a little bit of redundancy in that code. You don't need

```
i.append(n)
return collatz(n)
```

in both the `if` and `else` branches, you can move them outside the `if...else` block.

Here's a modified version of your code. I've also changed the `/` operators to `//` so that the results of the divisions will be integers.

```
i = []

def collatz(n):
    print(n)
    if n==1:
        return i
    if n%2 == 0:
        n = n // 2
    else:
        n = ((n*3) + 1) // 2
    i.append(n)
    return collatz(n)

# Test

print(collatz(12))
```

**output**

```
12
6
3
5
8
4
2
1
[6, 3, 5, 8, 4, 2, 1]
```